# Se fclose fecha um arquivo, como se fecha um arquivo aberto com o objeto SplFileObject?

Tags: php

Quando abrimos um arquivo com `fopen`, utilizamos a função `fclose` para fechar o manipulador desse arquivo.

```
 $handle = fopen('file.txt', 'r');

 fclose($handle);
```

Porém a minha curiosidade é: E quando utilizamos o objeto `SplFileObject`? Ele não tem o método `fclose`.

Como é que o arquivo é fechado quando instanciamos essa classe para abrí-lo?

```
$file = new SplFileObject('file.txt', 'r');

$file-> // Como faço para fechar?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta setar ele para `null`

```
$file = new SplFileObject('file.txt', 'r');

$file = null;
```

Em geral objetos tem um *cleanup* no destrutor, o fato de setar a variável para `null` já faz o que é necessário em muitos casos. E mesmo sem destrutor, o GC coleta os recursos normalmente, em algum momento (atenção, leia até o fim).

Notar que isso não necessariamente se aplique a qualquer classe. Para ter certeza, você precisa ver a documentação da classe específica, ou analisar a implementação se tiver acesso aos fontes.

Inclusive, de acordo com um comentário no manual, por ter uma propriedade privada não-documentada que segura o *file pointer*, os arquivos ficam travados na existência do objeto.

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.splfileobject.php#113149

Comment: +1 interessante, então funciona da mesma forma que no PDO. Legal