# Como validar a estrutura de um ficheiro de texto em PHP?

Tags: php

Criei um espaço *admin* no qual os usuários depositam ficheiros do tipo **.txt** no meu **FTP**.

Gostaria de impôr um formato. Exemplo todo o ficheiro deve conter duas três colunas separadas por um ponto e virgula.

**Exemplo** :

ficheiro_valido.txt

> nom;idade;altura
>  nom;idade;altura
>  nom;idade;altura

Todo ficheiro que não respeita esse formato deve ser ignorado.

**Exemplo**:

ficheiro_invalido.txt

> casa;idade;cidade;altura
>  vila;idade;pai;filhos
>  nom;idade;altura

Comment: Você quer checar o numero de colunas, é isto? Por exemplo, limitar para 3, se todas linhas tiverem 3, então é valido, caso contrário é inválido

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento extamente isso ... no momento de fazer upload eu preciso verificar se o ficheiro respeita essa condicao ( três colunas ), nem mais nem menos !

Comment: Mas esse *upload* é feito via FTP direto ou com PHP?

Answer (score 8):

Tentei de várias maneiras criar algo eficiente, no entanto nenhuma forma conseguiu validar tudo, o que acabou fazendo eu ter que optar pelo `while` mesmo com `fgets` (ou `fgetcsv`).

Esse formato que você deseja é basicamente o CSV, no entanto este formato de arquivo não é algo tão avançado, é impossivel limitar o numero de colunas de forma "pratica", um exemplo de checagem seria isto:

```
<?php
function validaCSV($arquivo, $limite = 3, $delimitador = ';', $tamanho = 0)
{
    $handle = fopen($arquivo, 'rb');
    $valido = true;

    if ($handle) {
        while (feof($handle) === false) {
            $data = fgetcsv($handle, $tamanho, $delimitador);

            if ($data && count($data) !== $limite) {
                $valido = false; //Seta false
                break;
            }
        }

        fclose($handle);
    } else {
        $valido = true;
    }

    return $valido;
}
```

Exemplo de uso (o padrão de colunas esperado é `3`):

```
var_dump(validaCSV('arquivo.txt')); //Checa se todas linhas tem 3 colunas
var_dump(validaCSV('arquivo.txt', 5)); //Checa se todas linhas tem 5 colunas
```

Irá retornar `true` se válido, caso contrário retornará `false`

---

Se quiser ler o arquivo acaso ele seja valido, use assim:

> Para evitar picos de memória acaso o arquivo seja invalido, criei dois whiles, é um pouco mais lento mas não irá consumir tanto o servidor (em caso de arquivos inválidos)
>
> **Nota:** no exemplo usei `yield` pois assim poderá usar dentro de um `while` proprio seu

```
function lerCSV($arquivo, $limite = 3, $delimitador = ';', $tamanho = 0)
{
    $handle = fopen($arquivo, 'rb');

    if ($handle) {
        while (feof($handle) === false) {
            $data = fgetcsv($handle, $tamanho, $delimitador);

            if ($data && count($data) !== $limite) {
                throw new Exception('O numero de colunas excedeu o limite de ' . $limite);
            }
        }

        //Volta o ponteiro para o inicio do arquivo para poder usar novamente o while
        rewind($handle);

        while (feof($handle) === false) {
            $data = fgetcsv($handle, $tamanho, $delimitador);

            if ($data) { //Impede linhas vazias de retornarem false como valor
                yield $data;
            }
        }

        fclose($handle);
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Arquivo inválido: ' . $arquivo);
    }
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
foreach(lerCSV('a.csv') as $linha) {
    var_dump($linha);
}
```

Irá emitir Exception acaso o arquivo seja invalido/inexistente ou acaso o numero de linha não seja o determinado na função (o padrão é `3`)

---

### Extra (com `SplFileObject`)

Estava a ver sobre a situação do arquivo ficar aberto no caso do **`yield`**, pois se houver um `break;` no `foreach` pode ocorrer do arquivo não ser fechado, no entanto o `SplFileObject` fecha o arquivo quando ocorre a classe é "destruída" (ocorrerá `__destruct` (interno) da classe), então neste momento o arquivo será "liberado", conforme explicado nesta pergunta:

- [Se fclose fecha um arquivo, como se fecha um arquivo aberto com o objeto SplFileObject?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125439/3635)

A versão com *SPL* ficou assim:

```
<?php

function SplLerCSV($arquivo, $limite = 3, $delimiter = ';', $enclosure = '"', $escape = '\\')
{
    $file = new SplFileObject($arquivo);
    $minCol = $limite - 1;

    while ($file->eof() === false) {
        $data = $file->fgetcsv($delimiter, $enclosure, $escape);

        if (isset($data[$minCol]) && count($data) !== $limite) {
            throw new Exception('O numero de colunas excedeu o limite de ' . $limite);
        }
    }

    //Volta o ponteiro para o inicio do arquivo para poder usar novamente o while
    $file->rewind();

    while ($file->eof() === false) {
        $data = $file->fgetcsv($delimiter, $enclosure, $escape);

        if (isset($data[$minCol])) { //Impede linhas vazias de retornarem [ 0 => NULL ] como valor
            yield $data;
        }
    }
}

//Usando
foreach (SplLerCSV('a.csv') as $value) {
    var_dump($value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Validar a estrutura do ficheiro (.txt)

**PHP**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['botao'])) {
    $invalido="false";
    //Receber os dados do formulario
    $arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];

    //ler todo o arquivo para um array
    $dados = file($arquivo_tmp);

    //percorrer o array para verificar a estrutura de cada linha
    foreach($dados as $linha){
        //deve conter 3 nomes de colunas separadas por ; (ponto e virgula)
        if (count(array_filter(explode(';', $linha))) !== 3){
            echo "Nananinanão, estrutura em desacordo";
            //inviabiliza o upload
            $invalido="true";
            //finaliza a execução do foreach na primeira ocorrência inválida.
            break;
        }
    }

    if($invalido=="false"){
        echo "estrutura ok";
        //upload aqui
    }

}
?>
```

Formulário usado no teste on-line.

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Arquivo</label>
    <!--Campo para fazer o upload do arquivo com PHP-->
    <input type="file" name="arquivo"><br><br>          
    <button type="submit" name="botao">Upload</button>
</form>
```

[teste on-line aqui](http://kithomepage.com/sos/validar_txt.php)

Comment: Eu diria que é possível otimizar, levemente, o código, pois se `substr_count($z, ';')` retornar um valor diferente de 2, o arquivo já é inválido, então você poderia parar a análise na primeira ocorrência. Se o arquivo tiver 1000 linhas e a primeira ja estiver errada, por quê analisar as outras 999? E é válido notar que esta solução não é recomendada se existir a possibilidade de arquivos muito grande, pois não só armazena o conteúdo do arquivo em memória como armazena duas vezes: uma no *array* `$dados`, outra na *string* `$result`.

Comment: Aliás, analisando melhor, a chamada de `substr_count` poderia acontecer no primeiro `foreach` e segundo, que utiliza `$result`, nem deveria existir, pois resulta em erro de sintaxe, visto que `$result` é uma *string*. No PHP, *string* não é um tipo iterável. Acho que você editou o código da outra resposta, mas deixou muita coisa passar - na outra você também utilizava um *foreach* em uma *string*, o que é estranho estar funcionando na sua página.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, é verdade, editei a resposta e acho que agora ficou bom. Juro que eu não sabia que `$dados = file($arquivo_tmp);` retornava um array, por isso que na primeira resposta fiz daquela forma!

Comment: É, melhorou bastante :D

Comment: Adorei a mensagem de erro para o caso de desacordo